# SSIS/SQL: Move data prepared in multiple related staging tables to "the real" tables without overwriting existing data (appending)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Goal: Getting (non personalized) data from PROD to DEV with a selection which I managed to get from the source (using parameters in this workflow.

*Edit: Since I prepared all the data already using SSIS, offcourse using a SQL command to move (and not in SSIS) is also ok.*

My idea:

[image]

1. During the export of these tables I added an attribute "OriginalTransactionId" to the set.
2. I am looking up all other id that are existing in the database.
   The TransactionDetail set has the (old) transactionid. So I can lookup the new ID using the "original transactionid" and put the in a table.
3. Here is my problem, transferring from the staging tables into the database.

All of this data is not there with new autonumbered ID's (starting from 1) becaue the staging tables were empty.

**How can I move the data from the staging tables into the tables with already data AND hold the referential integrity they have in the staging tables?**

Is it build in functionality if you say they you want to copy multiple tables to existing ones?

Please, I hope someone can answer me this question.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand you would like to replicate data from different environments. Following the idea of [Merge Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) you can populate your tables with [rowguid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) column which will be your unique referance. So you don't need to keep the same IDs.

An abstract idea will be the following:

```
INSERT INTO Transaction (Rowguid,,,,)
    SELECT ROWGUID,,,,
    FROM StageTransaction

INSERT INTO TransactionDetail (TransactionID, rowguid,,,,)
    SELECT t.ID, st.rowguid, st.*
    FROM StageTransaction st
    INNER JOIN StageTransactionDetail sd ON st.Transaction_ID
    INNER JOIN Transaction t ON st.ROWGUID = t.ROWGUID
```

Comment: I can't extend the tables that are in the database.I can extend the Staging tables, but the other of the "real" database I can't extend for the purpose of this data migration